# Making Debbuing Electron Apps with VS Code Work Well

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I have a TypeScript based Electron app that I am developing in VS Code.  Presently my debugging set-up is as follows:

1. A launch configuration entry for the Electron Launcher
2. A launch configuration entry for the electron Renderer

The launcher debugs within VS code just fine, however the render never attaches.  I can use the Chrome debugger in the browser, but none of the sourcemaps for the TypeScript work properly, the wrong lines are mapped.  For example, the actual break point might be on line 50, but the debugger stops at line 65.

In an ideal world, I would be able to debug TypeScript from within VS code.  Is there a way to achieve this?  Is there a way to get Chrome to handle the source maps properly so I can actually use the developer tools for debugging?

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/myapp-electron/",
            "program":  "${workspaceRoot}/myapp-electron/dist/main/main.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/myapp-electron/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                "."
            ],
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/myapp-electron/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9223,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/myapp-electron",
            "timeout": 30000
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Can you describe how you're trying to debug the renderer? For me, after launching the program ("Electron: Main"), I switch to "Electron: Renderer", launch that, then select the renderer file from the dropdown and then refresh the main page (Ctrl+R with devtools open)

Comment: I was just attaching after Main completed launching.  I'll try refreshing the browser and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug both the main process and the renderer process from vscode.
Visit this link [vscode-recipes/Electron](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron).

There you will find a launch.json, you can use that as a reference. here is an example:

```
  {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Electron: Main",
          "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
          "runtimeArgs": [
              "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
              "."
          ],
          "windows": {
              "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "Electron: Renderer",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9223,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "timeout": 30000
      }
  ],
  "compounds": [
      {
          "name": "Electron: All",
          "configurations": [
              "Electron: Main",
              "Electron: Renderer"
          ]
      }
  ]
```

}

**NOTE**: In order to debug the renderer process, you *NEED TO RUN* the main process beforehand.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35333855)